# can we use ArrayList as value(datatype) in key-value pair of HashMap?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

can we use ArrayList as value(datatype) in key-value pair of HashMap?.
will there be any issues, if it is possible?
provide an alternative.

Comment: Do you have a good reason to suspect otherwise? Writing code would be the fastest way to find out.

Comment: Yes, you can use any object as a value in a hash map. Why should it cause problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little test with `jshell` (comes with OpenJDK 13):

```java
var map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
map.put("first", new ArrayList<String>());
map.get("first").add("one");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     Map<Integer, List<Integer>> m_Map1 = new 
      HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
       // Add values
        m_Map1.put(1, new ArrayList<Integer>(list1));
         m_Map1.put(2, new ArrayList<Integer>(list2));
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.